# Comsol: Infinite Element Domain module

Tags: comsol

I want to simulate a 2D heat transfer process in the subsurface on a region which is infinite on the r-direction. So, as you know, the very basic way to model this is to draw a geometry that is very long in the r direction. I have done this, and the results that I obtain is correct as in this case, the results are matched with the analytical solution. As you know, there is a capability in Comsol called infinite element domain which serves the purpose to the problem mentioned above. In this case, we need to define a limited geometry on which we want to solve the PDE, and also need to draw a small domain acting as the Infinite Element Domain. However, in this case, the results are not correct because they are not matched with the analytical solution. Is there anything that I am missing to correctly use Infinite Element Domain in comsol?

Any help or comment would be appreciated.

**Edit:
I edited the post to be more specific.**
Please consider the following figure where a fluid with high temperature is being injected into a region with lower temperature:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQycC.png

The equation to solve is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrZcK.png

With the following initial and boundary conditions (note that the upper and lower boundary condition is no-flux):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7pHo.png

We want to obtain the temperature profile over the length of rw<r<140 m (rw is very small and is equal to 0.005 m here) at different times. One way to model this numerically in Comsol is to draw a rectangle that is 2000 m in the r-direction, and get results only in the span of r [rw,140] m:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKCOi.png

The results of this case is fine, because they are well-matched with the analytical solution.

Another way to model this is to replace the above geometry with a bounded one that is [rw, 140] m in the r-direction and then augment it with an Infinite Element domain that is meshed mapped, as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9ksm.png

Here, I have set the thickness of Infinite Element to 10 m in the r-direction. However, the results in this case are not matched with the analytical solution (or the above case where Infinite Element domain was not used). Is there anything that I am missing in Comsol? I have also changed some variables with regard to Infinite Element in Comsol such as physical width or distance, but I didn't see any changes in the results.

BTW, here are the results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdaPH.png

Comment: Have you made the mesh so that it "stretches" properly in the r-direction?  The mesh shouldn't be allowed to freely set itself in the direction that is simulating infinite length.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How can I set this? I have gone to "geometry" tab within the Infinite Element Domain, and set "r" as the stretching direction, and also set its distance very large (10000 m). If that's what you are saying, yes, and the results are the same! No correcting.

Comment: Actually, I'm talking specifically about the mesh.  If you look about half way down this page (https://www.comsol.com/support/knowledgebase/1272), you'll find some photos of the mesh.  You want the exterior mesh to be Mapped or Swept.  If you'd like some more details about how to do that, I can help you with it.

Comment: Thanks @rdipert; I have done this as well. The mesh on the IED is mapped. However, I don't know what is wrong, and why the results are wrong. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, without looking at the specific model and analytic solutions you're trying to solve for, I don't know what else to say.  Every time I think I find an issue with COMSOL when trying a simple confirming solution (as you are doing), I end up finding that it was user error.

Comment: @rdipert, thanks for your reply. I have now edited my post and added more information including the equation and how I have drawn the geometry in both cases. Maybe Infinite Element domain is not meant for this, and I am mistaken.